# How do I use IIS (not express) with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015

I have an ASP .NET web site project that was developed in Visual Studio 2012. We just migrated the project to Visual Studio 2015.

I've googled around and I keep reading about a "Create Virtual Directory" button and a "Use Local IIS" option but neither are present. In the project properties page all I see are the options "Use default Web server" and "Use custom server" along with a "Base URL" text field.

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 Pro.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled IIS in Windows Features?

- Press the Windows Key and type Windows Features.
- Select the first entry Turn Windows Features On or Off.
- Make sure the box next to IIS is checked. If it is not checked, check it and it will install everything you need. Be patient as this could take a few minutes.

IIS should now be accessible from Control Panel > Administrative Tools

You should now be able to go to the properties page of you application and change your website setting from IIS Express to Local IIS

Comment: Yes, IIS is installed.